# How to A/B split a table as part of a query

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automation

Hey guys have a simple use case;

I want to take a table and assign 80% of the records a variable of 'A' and the remaining 20% of records a variable of 'B'

I know I could easily accomplish this in 2 separate queries by having Query1 SELECT TOP(X) PERCENTAGE and then Query2 apply the other variable to the remainder, but wondering if there's a way to do it in 1 query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hate [NTILE()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but it likely is your easiest way to accomplish this. NTILE iterates through the rows and delegates them into a specified number of groups.

You would create a subquery assigning a number 1 - 10 via NTILE and then in your top level query, you would create a case statement to separate these into 'A' and 'B'.

Like so:

```sql
SELECT SubscriberKey,
CASE 
  WHEN n IN (1,2) THEN
    'A'
  ELSE
    'B'
END
FROM (
  SELECT SubscriberKey,
  NTILE(10) as n
  FROM [myDE]
)
```

This will assign a number in each row via the subquery using `NTILE(10)`. You want to have 1-10 as then each number represents 10% of your audience. You then use the case statement to grab those that were assigned number 1 and number 2 (10% + 10% = 20%) these will be your 'A' audience of 10%. You then just need an ELSE statement to assign 'B' to the other 80% of your audience.

This will then effectively have your audience split into A/B inside the same DE via a single query.

Comment: Thanks Gortonington! Just realized a simpler solution that i think i'll go with. Basically set the default value to "A" and then the query will SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT and apply value "B"

Answer (score 0):

Just realized a simpler solution to this - Set default value to "A" and then use SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT and apply value "B"

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about if possible with one query(I want to say no though) but a simpler option way would be Random split of the data extension.
Refer: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_random_de.htm&type=5

Comment: Doesn't work for my use case. the file will have people who should receive touchpoint 1,2,3 and 4. I will need to split touchpoint 1 folks 80/20, and so on and so forth. Random data extension doesn't allow me to include that logic